# How to dynamically add latitude and longitude inside a iframe map url using angular ngFor?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am creating an application that loads images, data, and a latitude and longitude from server. I used this json data and parse it and display in html. Everythings works fine.. But i need to add the latitude and longitude to the url specified in html page which is parsed fro JSON.

For ex i tried:

```
<iframe 
                            width="300" 
                            height="170" 
                            frameborder="0" 
                            scrolling="no" 
                            marginheight="0" 
                            marginwidth="0" 
                            src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q="+details.latitude+","+details.longitude+"&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed">
                           </iframe>
```

Here i get the latitude and longitude as:

> details.latitude

and

> details.longitude

How can i include the data inside the url.. 
I got an error as:

> compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected
>   closing tag "iframe". It may happen when the tag has already been
>   closed by another tag. For more info see
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("s?q="details.latitude","details.longitude"&hl=es;z=14&output=embed">
>                              [ERROR ->]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use double quotes inside another double quotes and the second thing you need to do is bind the data whatever you get in details.latitude and details.longitude if you are using it inside the html page.

You can pass a function and get the url try this:

in your component.ts:

```
someFn(param1,param2){  //call this function from html
   let url = `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${param1},${param2}&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed` // notice carefully the backticks dont confuse it with quotes ('' or " ")
   return url
}

<iframe>
    ...
[src]="someFn(details.latitude,details.longitude)">
</frame>
```

Comment: `compiler.js:26064 Uncaught Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
        Statement: //maps.google.com/maps?q={{details.latitude}},{{details.longitude}}&output=embed`

Comment: try this and check once :  [src]="https://maps.google.com/maps?q={{details.latitude}},{{details.longitude}}&hl=es;z=14&amp;output=embed">

Answer (score 0):

first of all we can't bind latitude and longitude dynamically in iframe it will give us error
so you need to do some logic in ts file if you are using angular
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';
then assign a variable mapurl:SafeResourceUrl
in NgOnint Do:
  this.mapurl=this.dom.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(`https://maps.google.com/maps?q=${lat},${lng}&hl=es;z=14&output=embed`)  //you need to assign lat and lng from backend
      }
in html in iframe just pass [src]="mapurl"
you will get the map with the desired output